# update-rc.d ignoring sequence numbers

Tags: init.d, rc.d

I'm trying to set up my system so that the emacs daemon starts after the machine boots.  I've created the file /etc/init.d with the commands I want executed, but when execute update-rc.d, it ignores the sequence numbers I supply.

```
[host /etc/init.d]$ sudo update-rc.d -n emacs defaults 10 02
insserv: enable service ../init.d/emacs -> /etc/init.d/../rc0.d/K01emacs
insserv: enable service ../init.d/emacs -> /etc/init.d/../rc1.d/K01emacs
insserv: enable service ../init.d/emacs -> /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S02emacs
insserv: enable service ../init.d/emacs -> /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S02emacs
insserv: enable service ../init.d/emacs -> /etc/init.d/../rc4.d/S02emacs
insserv: enable service ../init.d/emacs -> /etc/init.d/../rc5.d/S02emacs
insserv: enable service ../init.d/emacs -> /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/K01emacs
insserv: dryrun, not creating .depend.boot, .depend.start, and .depend.stop
[host /etc/init.d]$
```

I'm confused as to why the last two arguments of the command are ignored and whether or not I can ignore the fact that I'm setting the start sequence number to such a low value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update-rc.d defaults` doesn't process any other arguments; it uses information from the init script's [LSB headers](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initscrcomconv.html) to determine the priority to use (the sequence number), and to determine in which runlevels to start and stop the service.

If your script only depends on `$local_fs`, it's normal for it to end up with a low sequence number; if you look in `/etc/rc2.d` you'll see quite a few start links with low sequence numbers. If your script doesn't specify its own runlevels, the defaults are used: start in levels 2—5, stop in levels 0, 1 and 6. To define your own values you'd typically use a header such as

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: emacs
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start and stop the Emacs daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

(adjusting the various values as necessary).

You can also use `update-rc.d enable` and `update-rc.d disable` to respectively enable and disable a script in a specific runlevel (*e.g.* `update-rc.d emacs disable 3`).